# How to correctly code when pasting information from outside of Excel using VBA with different numberformats?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns with information that I copy from a back-end program we use. I'm pasting these 3 columns in cell B1 with column B containing numbers, column C contains text and column D are numbers which need to be converted into euro's

Below is the code that I have and is working. I'm trying to optimize the last bit, this was done by the macro recorder and seems to be the only piece of codes that works.

```
'Roy Arnts 28-9-2020 Optimize oude code
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Worksheet
Dim t As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim d As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set i = Sheets("InputOmzet")
Set t = Sheets("Targetoverzicht")
Set d = i.Range("D:D")

'Roy Arnts 28-9-2020  Paste omzet vanuit CS
       
ws.Range("B1").Select
ws.Paste
    
'Roy Arnts 28-9-2020 Tekst naar euro

d.Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True**
```

Some code I already tried and either didn't work or didn't gave the results I wanted;

```
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 €"
    .NumberFormat = "Currency"
    .Style = "Currency"
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

With any of these combinations and code column D formats numbers as text and messes up all of my formulas build off that sheet.

What is the simplest way to code the bottom part to get the result I want?

As requested in the comments here is an example of the pasted information without macros.

[image: Raw input]

[image: After ws.Paste]

[image: TextToColums]

Comment: What does the raw data you are pasting look like?

Comment: Column 1 = Year or Month as a number, Column 2 = Name of salesperson and Column 3 = profit as a number. So an example would be 2020 Pete Example  1.000.000,83

Comment: Is column 3 really a number, or is it formatted as currenct (with currency symbol **and/or** thousand seperators?)

Comment: I've added a picture in the original post

Comment: I think it's related to regional settings, and that Excel is US centric.  Try adding `DecimalSeparator:=",", ThousandsSeparator:="."` to your `TextToColumns` parameter list and specifying Fiels info for all columns (`FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1))`)

Comment: On the regional setting question, what are you PCs' settings? And what format do you want? (set one up manually, and post an image of the formatted cell, and the Number Format window)

Comment: My PC at home and my cloud environment from work both run with Dutch settings. You edited my original post, thank you for that, but one revision was wrong. The current piece of code with TextToColumns does work. It seems to be the only way to get what I want but I don't understand why this works and the other code doesn't. In my opinion there should be an easier way to code this right?

Comment: I reverted that part of the edit (ok now?).  I'm sure there will be a simple solution, once we get to the nub of the issue!  Just to clarify: the image you added is the data _after_ the `TextToColumns` code  has run, and _before_ you try to apply formats, right?

Comment: The reason I'm focussing on the `TextToColumns` is I'm not yet sure that the currency values have been imported as _numbers_ (and not _text_)  If they are text, that would explain why the Format code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Chris, it is ok now. Sorry if i'm not being clear in my answers. The image is done after I paste the information in Excel without running any form of code. When I paste the currency is formatted as numbers. The problem is that when I start running the code it becomes text and the current `TextToColumns` is the only code that i've found to correctly format it to Euro.

Comment: Are you saying that when you paste the data, it ends up in three columns? If so, your TextToColumns code does _nothing_ to the currency column.

Comment: I've uploaded to more pictures in the original post. Picture 1 is when I paste without code. Picture 2 is after I start the code and run `ws.Paste`. Picture 3 is after the line of code with `TextToColumns`

Comment: You are correct regarding not doing anything with currency. I already set that column to currency and when I run the code `TextToColumns` changes it from text to number and than uses the formatted cell setting. So it does not set it to Euro it just converts it from number as text to number as number.